# Is it possible to transpile C# version 10 or 11 code to older versions of the C# language?

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to transpile C# language version 10 or 11 source code to older versions of the C# language? Just like there are transpilers for Javascript to port code written in newer versions of Javascript to older versions of Javascript.

Comment: I don't think so. Because not all the new features are pure syntactic sugars of existing features.

Comment: Bear in mind that there have been CLR changes to accommodate certain language features. Most obviously, if you wanted to transpile back to C# 1, everything with generics goes out the window.

Comment: You need to take into consideration that C# Versions and .Net Versions are not really independent of one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing pre-rolled. Some features *can* be represented in down-level languages -and some tools offer *similar* features - for example, IIRC "Reflector" allowed you to specify the language version when *decompiling IL*, but: decompiled code can also frequently include things that *can't actually be represented in pure C#*, and: not all up-level features *can be* represented in down-level C#. Simple features like simple properties: sure, but: they're not hard to do manually *anyway*.

In most cases, however, you can use an *up-level* C# version on a down-level project, by using the `<LangVersion>` element in the csproj; for example, `<LangVersion>10</LangVersion>` or `<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>`. This is probably the better route to explore here. Some language features demand runtime support - which makes them framework-version dependent; some language features just require *specific types to exist*, and will work if you define those types locally or import them as a package (for example, `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`).

Comment: Thank you this is the most useful answer (the answer by JonasH was also helpful), mostly this is about going back to C# 7.3 and .NET Framework 4.8 and using C# pattern matching features of the later language versions wondering if I could use these by setting the LangVersion to C# 10 in a Office VSTO add-in project!

Comment: @DotNETAfficionado I don't know a lot about VSTO, but in general: if you deploy as *compiled binaries*, then the language version shouldn't matter - but if VSTO has special project types that don't work in SDK-style project files, then ... it could be painful; if you deploy as *source scripts*, then: I expect that to not work.

Answer (score 3):

No. But that is not the important question.

C# code is compiled to CIL code, that is executed by the **runtime**. Some language features are "syntactic sugar" and can be used on any runtime. These can typically be used by just setting the [langversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version) to "latest" in the project file.

Other features, like the new "generic math", require new runtime features, so it cannot be used with older **runtimes**. So if you want to use the new features you would essentially have to bundle the entire runtime with your application, and that is already one of the ways .Net core applications can be deployed. So just create a self contained deployment bundle.